# How do I create a Seaborn FactorPlot with different X-axis labels?

Tags: pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

I have a long-form data frame loosely defined as follows

- A column of y-values ("price")
- A column of category labels ("Number of Apples", "Fraction of grapes")
- A column of category values (1,2,3,4,5 for the former, 0.1, 0.2 0.3 for that the latter.)

I'd like to use a FactorPlot to get the general trend for the different categories, but `sns.FactorPlot(x='category_value', y='price', col='category', data=df)` munges all of the different category labels into the same axis. Is it possible to limit the levels of the category label used in each facet of the FactorPlot to only those that are present?

Comment: Possibly, possibly not; can you provide a [mcve] of the issue, such that one can clearly see the issue and test possible solutions?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have resolved my issue by re-reading the docs; [sns.PairGrid](http://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.PairGrid.html) can take a list of `x_vars`. The `PairGrid` will then confine all category variable levels to the appropriate grid cell.

Answer (score 0):

you can also use [FacetGrid](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.FacetGrid.html#seaborn.FacetGrid):

> In particular, FacetGrid is used to draw plots with multiple Axes where each Axes shows the same relationship conditioned on different levels of some variable.